# How to calculate bit strength of Integer Factorization Cryptography (IFC) such as RSA using Python

Tags: rsa, complexity

I would like to know how to calculate the bit-strength of Integer Factorization Cryptography (IFC) such as RSA by using Python. I gathered it is based off the complexity of factorizing the modulus (public key). I want to be able to calculate the bit strength of arbitrary key-lengths of RSA for example, such as 4096 which is not given by NIST etc.

This is similar to this question [Security strength of RSA in relation with the modulus size](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8687/security-strength-of-rsa-in-relation-with-the-modulus-size), where the answer is provided by using Mathematica.

The fastest publicly known algorithm for factoring is the General Number Field Sieve (GNFS). This has the complexity defined in L-notation. The formulae includes little-o 1, which I'm not sure how to fit into the calculations, in the Mathematica example it is left out (treated as being equal to 1).

Here is the relevant Mathematica code:

> I generated these numbers with the following Mathematica code:
>
> ```
> ({#, N@Log2@g[#]} &) /@ {1024, 2048, 3072, 7680, 15360}
> ```
>
> where g is defined as:
>
> ```
> g[b_] := Exp[(64/9 * Log[2^b])^(1/3) * (Log[Log[2^b]])^(2/3)]
> ```

If I understand correctly taking log2 of the exp would cancel out, so the result it's equivalent to just:`(64/9 * Log[2^b])^(1/3) * (Log[Log[2^b]])^(2/3)`.

I have tried the following Python code but it seems to be way off.

```
import fractions
import math

ln = math.log

n = pow(2, 1024)  ## change for other RSA key-sizes

a = fractions.Fraction(1,3)
c = pow(fractions.Fraction(64,9), fractions.Fraction(1,3))
# c = 1.9229994270765445

def g(a, c, n):
  return math.exp(c * pow(ln(n), a) * pow(ln(ln(n)), 1 - a))

x = g(a, c, n)
# x = 1.3158442944491604e+26
s = ln(x)
# s = 60.1416909264604
```

The result for 1024 is 60.14, whereas NIST says 80, and Mathematica got 86.77. The results for other key-sizes are all way off.

This is the results from Mathematica (3rd column) which are very close to NIST (1st column).

```
Strength  RSA modulus size   Complexity bit-length
  80        1024              86.76611925028119
 112        2048              116.8838132958159
 128        3072              138.7362808527251
 192        7680              203.01873594417665
 256       15360              269.38477262128384
```

My results from my Python code are (10243, 60.14), (2048, 81.02), (3072, 96.16), etc.

I thought maybe this is due to rounding errors, but using WolfRamAlpha (I don't have Mathematica which is why I'm trying to use Python instead) I get the same results as Python.

This is what I put into WolfRamAlpha:

```
(64/9 * Log[2^1024])^(1/3) * (Log[Log[2^1024]])^(2/3)
```

Decimal result is `60.14169092646040456...`. Pretty much same as my Python code. How did NIST and referenced answer get such different results. My code looks equivalent to me. I don't see my mistake.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: log2 is log base 2. $log2(exp(x))$ is x times 1.44270 approximately, which gives the expected results.

Comment: Can you make this an answer, since it is what I was doing wrong, I mistook log2 as log, whereas log * exp cancels, log2 * exp does not.

Comment: Can the downvoter mention the reason for the down-vote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(From comment so question can be closed properly)

log2 is log base 2. $log(exp(x))$ would cancel, but $log2(exp(x))$ is x times 1.44270 approximately, which gives the expected results