# How long does it take to crack RSA 1024 with a PC?

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis, factoring, decryption

Using an Intel Core i5 CPU, how long does it take to crack RSA using a key size of 1024 bit (generated using a secure key pair generation function)?

Suppose for instance that we have thousands of zombies or a big network of computers. To calculate all the combinations or possibilities, can we distribute the process through a big network of computers?

Comment: I think the standard estimate is $2^{40}$ work for 512-bit moduli and $2^{80}$ work for 1024-bit. A _very_ optimistic guesstimate would probably be "1 day" for the 512-bit modulus, so $2^{40}$ (1 trillion) days for 1024-bit moduli. Of course I didn't use actual performance numbers (so no proper answer).

Comment: Would you please tell me where or by which formula did you get 2^{80}?

Comment: it's basically rounded from https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8692/24949

Comment: What CPU family? What clock speed? How much RAM?

Comment: @forest It is not actually about one pc, it is about parallelized  computation using many Pcs,

Comment: @R1w Sure, but precise hardware information is necessary to make _accurate_ estimates. However you should assume that RSA 1024 can be broken with sufficient computing power (whether a _huge_ number of consumer PCs or a specialized ASIC).

Comment: @forest you asked for " CPU family, clock speed, RAM" is there any formula for calculation power of processing in this case?

Comment: Related: [How to estimate the time needed to crack RSA encryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4518/11825)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

RSA-768 took [2000 years of 2.2Ghz single-core Opteron from the year 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-768).

[DJB et al wrote in 2013](https://www.hyperelliptic.org/tanja/vortraege/facthacks-29C3.pdf) (see page 30) (see also: [29C3: FactHacks (EN)](https://youtu.be/95N2KXqH5cs?t=2100); slide 87/112; about 10 minutes) that RSA-1024 would take $2^{70}$ differences with $2^{24}$ per machine per second in 2009, so 2 million years. Hardware improved since then, and GNFS can use GPUs, so maybe better, but about a million years I guess.

Absolutely the computation can be parallelized to use many devices, for example to use a botnet, which is what DJB recommends. Whether one can have a botnet with a million devices with strong CPU/GPU that uses up a lot of power and not get noticed for a year, is another matter entirely.

Comment: So it makes Decryption-As-Service possible either for a legal issue or illegal.

Comment: Yes, Nadia Heninger (co-author of that presentation I linked, https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~nadiah/) tried to run such a service on the public cloud. AFAIK this service doesn't exist, but anyone can create it using open source software (http://cado-nfs.gforge.inria.fr/) and specialists can optimize the software for new hardware or to best use cloud spot instances, etc.