# exponent bit-length for hard DL (128-bit security)

Tags: rsa, quadratic-residuosity, domain-parameters

Following up on my [previous post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/104084/hardness-of-dl-in-group-of-quadratic-residues-product-of-safe-primes), I thought I might get a more concrete answer if I gave a more concrete question.

I require 128-bit security so I choose a [3072-bit RSA modulus](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8687/security-strength-of-rsa-in-relation-with-the-modulus-size) ($\ell_n=3072$). Specifically I choose $n=pq=(2p'+1)(2q'+1)$ that is a product of safe primes $p$ and $q$.

Now, I want to choose $\ell_\Lambda$ such that finding DL with $\ell_\Lambda$-bit exponents is hard in $QR_n$, for an adversary who does not know the factorization of $n$, with *128 bits of security.*

Note that the order of $QR_n=\phi(n)/4=p'q'$, so each element has large order.

Is choosing $\ell_\Lambda=256$ sufficient as suggested in the answer to my [previous post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/104084/hardness-of-dl-in-group-of-quadratic-residues-product-of-safe-primes)?

Comment: Is the factorization of $n$ secret? With $p$ and $q$ known, we can reduce a DLP modulo $n$ to two DLP modulo $p$ and $q$, and with each 1536-bit these would not be 128-bit secure (more like 100-bit, give or take a lot).

Comment: @fgrieu: as explained in his previous post, the factorization of $n$ is secret

Comment: @fgrieu edited question to clarify $p$ and $q$ are unknown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second that with the factorization of $n$ remaining secret, as assumed in the [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2001/019.pdf) linked in that [previous question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/104084/555) (in particular by making the strong RSA assumption), the Discrete Logarithm Problem modulo $n$ is believed no easier that if $n$ was prime. And therefore, the best methods to solve that DLP have expected cost the lowest of:

1. a few times $2^{\ell_\Lambda/2}$ multiplications modulo $n$, for methods based on collision search like [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms)/[kangaroo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_kangaroo_algorithm) and [distributed variants](https://doi.org/10.1007/PL00003816).
2. about the cost of (G)NFS factorization of $n$; see [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/697.pdf) for about the state of the art, implying that the cost of factorization of $n$ and DLP for prime $n$ have roughly similar cost.

With $\ell_\Lambda=256$ and $\ell_n=3072$, (1.) is believed to be the least infeasible, and this parametrization is believed to give 128-bit security, disregarding hypothetical [CRQC](https://crqc.grieu.fr).